# payara micro 5.182 does not deploy web application compiled with java10

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, payara, java-10, payara-micro

When starting payara 5.182 using Java10 it throws the following IllegalArgumentException

```
 [java]   Exception while visiting WEB-INF/classes/com/Service.class of size 1163
 [java] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 [java]     at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:160)
 [java]     at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:143)
 [java]     at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:418)
 [java]     at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:359)
 [java]     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:165)
 [java]     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:127)
 [java]     at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:345)
 [java]     at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:68)
 [java]     at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:304)
 [java]     at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:293)
 [java]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
 [java]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
 [java]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
 [java]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
 [java] ]]
```

I assume it is caused by the repackaged asm class ClassReader (I think it's the asm version 6.0)

```
public ClassReader(final byte[] b, final int off, final int len) {
    this.b = b;
    // checks the class version
    if (readShort(off + 6) > Opcodes.V9) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    ...
}
```

In the asm version 6.2, the class ClassReader seems to be Java11 compliant

```
ClassReader(
  final byte[] classFileBuffer, final int classFileOffset, final boolean checkClassVersion) {
  this.b = classFileBuffer;
  // Check the class' major_version. This field is after the magic and minor_version fields, which
  // use 4 and 2 bytes respectively.
  if (checkClassVersion && readShort(classFileOffset + 6) > Opcodes.V11) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "Unsupported class file major version " + readShort(classFileOffset + 6));
  }
  ...
}
```

The question is, how can I get the payara 5.182 running with Java10 ?

Comment: are you using any dependency management tool like maven? can you look into the transitive dependencies of payara jar that's in use and confirm the version of ASM..doesn't seem like they've upgraded to the latest version from their release notes.

Comment: I start the payara-micro (payara-micro-5.182.jar) out of eclipse photon via an ant task while the deployed application was created via maven. For finding out the asm version i looked into the manifest file from the MICRO-INF/runtime/asm-repackaged.jar and this is Bundle-Version: 6.0

Comment: here you go https://asm.ow2.io/versions.html, the version 6.1 started learning what JDK 10 is and that's possibly the reason why you get an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Answer (score 1):

Payara Micro 5.182 does not support JDK9+, only JDK8. JDK11 support is anticipated for 5.184, in the last quarter of this year.

Comment: It seems that I have to move back to JDK8 or is there a possibillity to migrate the asm in payara to 6.2 ? I mean, payara 5.182 is shipped with asm and an additionally repackaged asm, so migration of the standard asm is no big deal, but what about the repackaged one, do you have any idea ? So that I do not have to wait until the official JDK11 support.

Comment: @bombadil Unfortunately updating asm alone is not enough to get Payara working on JDK 9+, as all dependencies of Payara need to be updated as well. The repackaged-asm comes from HK2, which is not JDK9+ ready.